# MATLAB R2016b ROS Initialization Problem on Windows 10 (rosinit doesn't working)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use newest version of MATLAB R2016b with Robotics System Toolbox. My computer has 64-bit Windows 10 Education OS.

İt's [Get Started with ROS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/examples/get-started-with-ros.html;jsessionid=d47041f02ff7070b32e4b8910991)

rosinit is working on Mac OS but the same command.

Problem is here:

I tried resolve of all combination on internet. But I didn't resolve this problem.

1- [rosinit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rosinit.html)

2- [ros initialization problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/207508/matlab-r2015a-ros-initialization-problem/)

```
rosinit
```

Problem is here:

```
Exception in thread "ROS Executor Thread" org.ros.exception.RosMessageRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: std_msgs.uint32
    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.get(MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.java:66)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator.generate(Md5Generator.java:44)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator$1.variableValue(Md5Generator.java:61)
    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionParser.parseField(MessageDefinitionParser.java:172)
    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionParser.parse(MessageDefinitionParser.java:107)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator.generateText(Md5Generator.java:86)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator.generate(Md5Generator.java:49)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator$1.variableValue(Md5Generator.java:61)
    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionParser.parseField(MessageDefinitionParser.java:172)
    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionParser.parse(MessageDefinitionParser.java:107)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator.generateText(Md5Generator.java:86)
    at org.ros.internal.message.Md5Generator.generate(Md5Generator.java:49)
    at org.ros.internal.message.topic.TopicDescriptionFactory.newFromType(TopicDescriptionFactory.java:36)
    at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.newPublisher(DefaultNode.java:280)
    at org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger.<init>(RosoutLogger.java:41)
    at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.start(DefaultNode.java:195)
    at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.access$000(DefaultNode.java:90)
    at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$1.run(DefaultNode.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: std_msgs.uint32
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.ros.internal.message.definition.MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.get(MessageDefinitionReflectionProvider.java:62)
    ... 20 more

Error creating the node /matlab_global_node_70133.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250041/matlab-r2016b-ros-initialization-problem-on-windows-10-(rosinit-doesn%27t-working)/) by [yucelokan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28799/yucelokan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-14**:
This is really more of a question for Mathworks support. Have you tried contacting them?

**Comment by [yucelokan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28799/yucelokan/) on 2016-12-15**:
How can I contact with them ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-18**:
If you don't have a local/regional Mathworks contact person, you could try any of the options on the Mathworks [support site](https://uk.mathworks.com/support/?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

**Comment by [yucelokan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28799/yucelokan/) on 2016-12-20**:
I GOT İT. The language of my computer was Turkish. I solved the problem when I made this English (United States).    :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I GOT İT. The language of my computer was Turkish. I solved the problem when I made this English (United States).    :) :)

---

Originally posted by [yucelokan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28799/yucelokan/) with karma: 26 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-20**:
Wow. That is rather surprising.

Have you had contact with Mathworks about this? I'm guessing they would like to know about such an issue.

Thanks for reporting back btw, much appreciated!

**Comment by [yucelokan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28799/yucelokan/) on 2016-12-20**:
Is not that enough? [It's a topic I created](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/316852-matlab-r2016b-ros-initialization-problem-on-windows-10-rosinit-doesn-t-working)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-20**:
That would seem like it should get their attention. Thanks for that.

**Comment by [dymzlr](https://answers.ros.org/users/33528/dymzlr/) on 2018-02-02**:
That didn't work for me. I'm using Matlab 2016a , WIN7 64 bit OS (default language : English ) ... when i try the 'rosinit' command. Same error occurs ... and i tried everything,but couldn't find the solution

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-02**:
As this is an officially supported Mathworks toolbox, I'd really recommend you post this on their support forums. The chances of getting a good answer are a lot higher then.

Do please post a link here to any issue you post on their fora.